# Правильно ли составлено предложение? Сомневаюсь, хотя

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

> А почему если все пальцы разной длины, но когда мы их сгибаем, то они все на одном уровне?

Предложение не моë — услышал в одном видео. Немножечко странно звучит, хотя кажется и верным, и нет. Не могу разобраться... И если верное, правильно ли знаки расставлены? А если неверное, как можно перефразировать? Совы, расскажите всë как можно подробнее. Очень интересно-таки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*А почему если все пальцы разной длины, но когда мы их сгибаем, то они все на одном уровне?*

1. Рассмотрим **отдельное предложение**: *Все пальцы разной длины, но **когда мы их сгибаем**, то они все на одном уровне.*
2. Вполне **корректное** предложение  с правильными знаками.  А чем оно **отличается** от исходного?

Понятное дело, это сочетание ***"а почему если".*** Это **детерминант,** который относится ко всему предложению.

Отделить его **знаком** не получится, но произносить нужно **с небольшой паузой.**

***А почему если** / все пальцы разной длины, но когда мы их сгибаем, то они все на одном уровне?*

Comment: Мне кажется, то перед _если_ не стоит запятая, то это потому, что мы испольжуем двойной союз ЕСЛИ..., ТО.

Comment: А чем двойной союз КОГДА...ТО хуже? Он на тех же правах)  Спасибо за вопрос!  Интересно было подумать над задачкой. Расставшись с математикой, я все же скучаю по ней.