# Нужна ли запятая? Сомневаюсь

Tags: запятые

> А что, если, делая викторину(,) — но только по русскому, если что, — давать ответ на вопрос не когда сам вопрос только написал, а потом, через время?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*А что, если, делая викторину — но только по русскому, если что, — давать ответ на вопрос не когда сам вопрос только написал, а потом, через время?*

Вставка в составе деепричастного оборота. Если убрать оборот, получится бред:

*А что, если — но только по русскому, если что, — давать ответ на вопрос не когда сам вопрос только написал, а потом, через время?*

Запятую перед вставкой не ставим, потому что она в составе деепричастного оборота, без которого вставка сама по себе **существовать не может**.

Comment: Почему получится бред?  Если убрать "если что", то   только два тире?

Comment: Я деепричастный оборот убрал. А без него нет вставной конструкции, потому что она относится к деепричастному обороту.

Comment: Нет, запятая, закрывающая деепричастный оборот, сохраняется: _А что, если, делая викторину — но только по русскому, — давать ответ на вопрос не когда сам вопрос только написал, а потом, через время?_

Comment: Ладно, но окончательное объяснение надо давать по Розенталю, а то в вашем ответе этого нет. Запятые в начале предложения не нужны (я так думаю). Иначе грамматика неяясная.

Comment: Какая у вас грамматика? Вид предложения какой?  Вариант здесь нестандартный.

Comment: @Sharon Здесь не о принятии ответа надо говорить (так как Лео принимает даже некачественные и неправильные ответы), а о вашем решении. У вас получается так: *Если делая викторину, давать ответ не сразу*. Что это за грамматика?

Comment: @Sharon *А что если делая викторину, давать ответ не сразу?* – тоже неправильно. *Давать ответ не сразу, а что если делая викторину?* ???

Comment: Лео делает викторину, в ней можно давать ответы сразу или нет. Я так поняла.  Предложение делится на две части, а не на четыре. И не надо ничего переставлять, мы не в детском саду.  Грамматический анализ нужен.

Comment: @Sharon Правильно, по-другому и не понять. Вот он и спрашивает: *А что если давать ответ не сразу?*

Comment: Не надо ломать предложение. Детский прием, а не анализ.  Я на таком языке разговаривать не буду, вы уж между собой говорите.

Comment: @Sharon Тогда говорите это Лео. Он сломал, воткнув оборот.

Comment: У него все нормально, у себя разберитесь. Вот то предложение https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476519/Правильно-ли-составлено-предложение-Сомневаюсь-хотя  Там "А почему если".

Answer (score 0):

```
 – Какой вид предложения?  
 – Какая разница, какой вид?
```

Правильно:

*А что если / делая викториИну — **но только по русскому, если что,** — // давать ответ на вопрос не когда сам вопрос только написал, а потом, через врЕмя?*

1. **ГРАММАТИЧЕСКИЙ АНАЛИЗ**

**Нужен ли он здесь?** Думаю, что нужен всегда, **и здесь в том числе.**

(1) Модель предложения: ***А что если / делая викторину**, //  давать ответ не сразу?*

(2) Предложение простое, **осложненное** деепричастным оборотом.

(3) Вид предложения: **односоставное инфинитивное**. Главный член предложения выражен инфинитивом "***давать***".
Независимый инфинитив широко используется в **вопросительных** предложениях.

(4) **ЧАСТИЦА** "***а что если***" со значением **условной возможности** относится  ко всему предложению (к его **предикативной основе**), это детерминант. Не следует делить ее на отдельные части, особенно с учетом **вставки** (структура предложения не будет правильно пониматься в целом).

(5) Содержание сказанного: **Может, делая викторину, // давать ответ не сразу?**

2. Вставка относится к **левой части**, поэтому первой  запятой перед тире нет. По Розенталю: запятая **перенесенная,** закрывает деепричастный оборот.

Вставка **не входит в состав** деепричастного оборота, но интонационно **смещена** в сторону оборота.

Comment: Частица ЧТО, ЕСЛИ всегда разбивается запятой. Во-вторых, давайте уберëм деепричастный оборот и вставку, входящую в неë: _А что, если давать ответ на вопрос не когда сам вопрос только написал, а потом, через время?_ частица ЧТО, ЕСЛИ и присоединительный союз А относятся ко второй части, а не к обороту.

Comment: Согласен с Максимом. Основная (смысловая) структура: *А что, если давать ответ*.

Comment: Вы не понимаете грамматическую модель предложения. Какое это предложение? Убирать и переклеивать ничего не надо. Так решайте. Предикативная основа и т.д.

Comment: Тем лучше, если согласны. Какой вид предложения?

Comment: Какая разница, какой вид?  [**(А) ЧТО, ЕСЛИ (БЫ),** *частица* (в вопросительном предложении)](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_759):  *А что, если устроить этим явно враждебным подлодкам маленькую ответную диверсию?* Г. Адамов, Тайна двух океанов. *А что, если бы можно было изменить высшие предначертания?* А. и Б. Стругацкие, Трудно быть богом. *А что, если бы этой счастливой встречи не произошло?* Л. Лагин, Старик Хоттабыч.

Comment: Нет, вы сначала про модель расскажите. Я, знаете ли, грамматику люблю, а не примеры.

Comment: Справка: В художественной литературе встречаются примеры непостановки запятой перед словом «если».  Зачем частицу на части делить, если это и так частица.

Comment: Примеры вы любите. :))  В вашем ответе тоже нет о виде предложения. А это и не требуется: предложение вопросительное. // И странно, вам и стилистика такая уже нравится?

Comment: Это все? А как же модель!  Так и не скажете?  Стилистика? Мне ответ М. не понравился, если что.  Поэтому даю свой ответ.

Comment: Про непостановку я видел. На то она и художественная литература. Можно и здесь не ставить, но дело-то не в начальной частице, а в деепричаст. обороте, который вклинивается в основу.

Comment: Вы так и не хотите указать модель? Мне это сделать? А я не хочу вам помогать, потому что вы все на одного.  Давайте, принимайте свои правильные ответы.  Идет честный разговор тет-а- тет, а вы вмешиваетесь помогать.  Мушкетеры так не поступали.

Comment: Sharon, при чём тут модель? Если хотите, напишите. Эта модель чётко написана в справочнике. А вы зачем-то просто включили "а что если" в оборот, но это неправильно. Вот и всё. Поэтому я и подключился сюда.

Comment: Я  отнесла частицу к деепричастному обороту. Это же частица.

Comment: Почему вы воспринимаете в штыки? Нормально ведь говорили. // Частица относится к основе. Всё.

Comment: Потому что нечестно, Максим дал ответ, пуст он его и защищает. //  К КАКОЙ ОСНОВЕ? Основу назовите.   //  Деепричастный оборот как вставка?  Мало нам  здесь одной вставки. // That is all.

Comment: Всё уже сказано выше. Ещё раз: *А что если давать*.